# Meaning of "approval rally"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read the following statement on news:

> [Trump's approval rally has disappeared](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/04/19/politics/trump-approval-rating-rally/index.html). (CNN.com)

After some research it seems the word **rally** has several meanings in political context.

- It can mean the public event where people gather in the streets to listen to a political speech
- It can also mean to call people together (figuratively) for a cause

But **approval rally** doesn't seem to fit either.

Maybe besides meaning the concrete gathering and the call for support, **rally** could also mean the support from the people itself (the result of gathering or call)? As if *"approval rally"* meant simply *popularity*, *political support* or *political backing* shown by citizens?

A further question: does **rally** apply only when the popularity of a politician has bumped after a period of steadiness? Or can it be used despite of that?

Thanks!

Comment: If a word is used metaphorically, as *rally* would seem to be in this instance, the only real test of validity, I suggest, would be if the reader/listener grasps the meaning. And in this case I think I do understand what is being said.

Comment: @WS2 Sorry, could you elaborate more? I think I don't fully understand your comment.

Comment: Consider that an army in retreat might "rally" and attack.  Or a sports team that is down ten points in the last quarter might "rally" and go on to win by eight.

Comment: And then, quite commonly, it is said that "the stock market has rallied."

Comment: @RicardoBaptista Do you know what a "metaphor" is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the whole article, you will see that ‘rally’ is used in the sense of *recovery*.  The recovery is in Trump’ “**approval ratings**”, which had reached a low ebb.

Had I been editing, I should have suggest replacing the ambiguous ‘rally’ (given Trump’s notorious propensity for holding huge public rallies) with the unambiguous word - the more so since vast hordes of readers limit themselves to scanning the headlines.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I read the whole article before posting here. What made me curious was **rally** appears both in headline meaning *recovery* (now I know it) and several times throughout the article (in expression *"rally 'round the flag"*) with a different sense. Though latter expression is a figurative for a political effect it originated from an actual reassembling (rally) of soldiers around the US flag.